# Changing Spaces Per Tab in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have a SCSS file I am currently working on.  The indentation is 4 spaces, but for some reason PHPStorm only moves the cursor 2 spaces every time I tab.  Is there a way to change this?  Strange thing is I have other files in the project (mostly JS) and they are tabbed 4 spaces.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style`
3. Now select your desired language (as it's configured on per language basis) and check the option on the **"Tabs and Indents" tab.**

[image]

If you are using the actual `Tab` symbol for intents then you will see the changes straight away. But if you use `Space` then you will need to invoke `Code | Reformat Code` (or similar `Code | Reformat File...`) to see the changes in the indents.

---

**In case if you have changed the settings in Code Style but still see the old/different settings being applied:** check if you have `.editorconfig` file(s) in your project and EditorConfig is enabled (by default).

The settings from such a file will **overwrite** your Code Style settings (it's expected as it's the nature of such files). In this case you will need to edit your `.editorconfig` file (or disable EditorConfig integration).

---

**P.S.** I prefer setting the [basic settings](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties) (like indent size, indent symbol etc) in the `.editorconfig` file. It's portable, flexible, and allows setting up different settings for files that do not have dedicated Code Style settings in the IDE.

Comment: A side note for those who has `.editorconfig` files in their projects and have "EditorConfig Support" plugin installed and enabled -- settings from `.editorconfig` files will overwrite your Code Style -- that's the nature of such files. This could be the case when you are facing "I've changed tab/indent size in IDE but it still uses different/old settings" situation.

Comment: LazyOne, thanks a lot! I've been wondering for a while while it doesn't work, finally the answer!

Comment: Under my Win7 PhpStorm 2016.2.1 needs to be restarted when tab width was changed. In Linux and Mac there are no such issues, everything works fine.

Answer (score 9):

After applying the settings, the tab will not apply right away. For this to work you have to **Code -> Reformat Code**

Answer (score 5):

You can set the tab and indent for each language you code in.
[image]